# Getting timeout error when trying to run async test in Mocha

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, mocha.js, chai

Recently, I decided to continue a old nodejs project. It's a small blog engine implemented with Express + MySQL module. I created different methods to integrate with the database by using a prototype-based class and assign those methods to it (eg `insert_post()`, `insert_author()`, etc). To connect, I have to create an instance object and call the appropriate method (eg `mysqlConn.delete_comment()`). Now I want to add some tests using mocha + chaijs. To simplify things, I wrote only one spec file and require all the additional test files.

*setup.js*

```
import MYSQL from '../../../../../app/models/database/MYSQL';
import CONFIG from '../../../../../app/config/config';

const ENV_VARS = CONFIG.testing;

const mysql = new MYSQL({
  host: ENV_VARS.db.host,
  user: ENV_VARS.db.user,
  password: ENV_VARS.db.password,
  database: ENV_VARS.db.database,
});

export default mysql;
```

*MYSQL.spec.js*

```
import mysqlConn from './setup';

describe('MYSQL#', function () {
  describe('authors', function () {
    beforeEach(function () {
      mysqlConn.query('TRUNCATE authors;');
    });

    require('./authors/insert_author');
    require('./authors/select_author');
  });
});
```

The problem I'm facing occurs when I try to test `select_author()` method. I get `Error: Timeout of 2000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, ensure "done()" is called; if returning a Promise, ensure it resolves.`

*select_author()*

```
import { expect } from 'chai';
import mysqlConn from '../setup';

describe('select_author()', function () {
  beforeEach(function() {
    mysqlConn.query('TRUNCATE authors;');

    mysqlConn.insert_author({
      name: 'admin1',
      email: 'admin1@email.com',
      avatar: 'https://some-img.com/admin1.png',
      description: 'web developer',
      role: 'admin'
    });

    mysqlConn.insert_author({
      name: 'admin2',
      email: 'admin2@email.com',
      avatar: 'https://some-img.com/admin2.png',
      description: 'web designer',
      role: 'admin'
    });

    mysqlConn.insert_author({
      name: 'writer1',
      email: 'writer1@email.com',
      avatar: 'https://some-img.com/writer1.png',
      description: 'blogger',
      role: 'writer'
    });

    mysqlConn.insert_author({
      name: 'writer2',
      email: 'writer2@email.com',
      avatar: 'https://some-img.com/writer2.png',
      description: 'marketer',
      role: 'writer'
    });
  });

  it('should return all authors.',function(done) {
    expect(function() {
      mysqlConn.select_author('*', function(err, res) {
        if (err) throw err;
        done();
      }).not.to.throw();
    });
  });
});
```

And here is the implementation of `select_author()`

```
module.exports = {
    /** 
     * Select an author entry.
     * @method select_author
     * @memberof MYSQL#
     * @param {!(string|Object)} select_details - The required properties to select a user.
     * @param {?HandleCallback} callback - The callback that handles the response.
     * @example
     * // gets all authors.
     * mysql.select_author('*');
     */
    select_author: function(select_details, callback) {
        if (!(callback instanceof Function)) callback = function() {};

        if (select_details == '*') {
            this.pool.getConnection(function(err, connection) {
                if (err) {
                    return callback(err);
                }
                connection.query(
                    'SELECT * FROM  authors',
                    function(err, result) {
                        connection.release();
                        if (err) {
                            callback(err);
                        } else {
                            callback(null, result);
                        }
                    }
                );
            });
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to remove `beforeEach()` hook inside `author_select()` but got the same error. Note that I already tested `insert_author()`. Is there anything wrong with my testing procedure that cause this issue? Here is the output of mocha:

```
MYSQL#
    authors
      insert_author()
        ✓ should return error if either `email`, `name`, `avatar`or `description` properties are false values.
        ✓ should return error if `role` property is set to value other than `writer` or `admin`.
        ✓ should return error if `email` is not valid email.
        ✓ should succeed. (2277ms)
      select_author()
        1) should return all authors.

  4 passing (12s)
  1 failing

  1) MYSQL# authors select_author() should return all authors.:
     Error: Timeout of 10000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, ensure "done()" is called; if returning a Promise, ensure it resolves.
```

**Note**:

1. I already tried `this.timeout()` without success.
2. The method is working as expected inside `app.js`
3. I have added `conslole.log` statements inside `insert_author()` callbacks. What I have discovered is that the `it()` is executed before `beforeEach()` hook end. I don't know if it is related with the problem -as I already said I tried the `it()` without `beforeEach()` and got the same error.

Comment: Use `done(err)` instead of throwing it, see if you get an actual error.

Comment: @MinusFour nope there is no output in the console.

Comment: One of the callbacks must not be being called then or it's throwing somewhere in the callbacks. This is why you should be using promises instead of the callback approach.